# passing $_POST data to a PDO function

Tags: php, pdo

It's more of a basic php issue than a pdo issue, but none the less I am getting error `'Notice: Undefined index: body in /home/downlowd/www/dev/launch.php on line 20'`
I tried to pass `$_POST` in a few places, but just made things worse.

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$attrs = array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true);
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$dbname, $db_username, $db_password, $attrs);
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$custlist = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM customer_list");
$carrierlist = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM carriers");
//$products = array();

$smsarrayobject = new ArrayObject($carrierlist);


if ($custlist->execute()) {
        while ($row = $custlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $prefix = $row['sms_num'];
                if ($carrierlist->execute()) {
                        while ($rows = $carrierlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $from = 'admin@telecomm.com';
                                $to = $prefix.$rows['carrieraddr'];
                                $body = $_POST['body'];
                                mail($to, $from, $body);
                        }
                }
        }
}
$pdo = null;
?>
<form action="" method="POST">
        Your Message Body <input name="body" type="text" />
        <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Stupid question but have you submitted the form first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check $_POST even before executing your code, this prevents to handle empty inputs, the best way is to check using isset() function:

```
if(isset($_POST['body']){
// your stuff

}
```

Comment: I tried if(isset) but I start getting SFP (stoopid freakin programmer) errors when I try to pass more than one variable in my if statement....  ->  if ($_POST['body'], $custlist->execute()) {
        while ($row = $custlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $prefix = $row['sms_num'];
                if($carrierlist->execute()) {
                        while ($rows = $carrierlist->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                                $body = $_POST['body'];
                                mail($to, $from, $body);
                        }
                }
        }
}

Comment: @Liam Sorsby  the form is on the same page.

Comment: your condition should be placed at very top! even before `require_once('config.php');`

Comment: Should be `if(isset($_POST['body']))` not `if($_POST['body'])`

Comment: Thank you very very much! I still have more work to go, you might see me again but that is working now.